# setting canvas with image dimetions

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am trying to set a canvas with a picture background. I want to make the image variable but that's for a different discussion.

Here is my code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];

var img = document.createElement('img');

img.onload = function () { alert(img.width + ' x ' + img.height); };

img.src='images/maps/de_dust2.jpg';

canvas.width  = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
```

When the page loads I get the alert with the correct pixel height and width however the canvas is not shown.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];

var img = document.createElement('img');

img.onload = function () {
    // you need to have thes in the onload, to have img width, height > 0
    canvas.width  = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    alert(img.width + ' x ' + img.height);
};

img.src='images/maps/de_dust2.jpg';
```

Comment: do you know why it need to be in the onload?  Thanks by the way.

Comment: Because only when it finished loading the image it knows the image size. When you had them after the img.onload they were executed before the image loaded, so you got 0 or NaN